# Vectorizing bits packing in C++

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, vectorization, rcpp

I'm writing a tool for operations on long strings of 6 different letters (e.g. >1000000 letters), so I'd like to encode each letter in less than eight bits (for 6 letters 3 bits is sufficient)

Here is my code:

```c++
Rcpp::RawVector pack(Rcpp::RawVector UNPACKED, 
                     const unsigned short ALPH_SIZE) {
  const unsigned int IN_LEN = UNPACKED.size();
  Rcpp::RawVector ret((ALPH_SIZE * IN_LEN + BYTE_SIZE - 1) / BYTE_SIZE);
  unsigned int out_byte = ZERO;
  unsigned short bits_left = BYTE_SIZE;

  for (int i = ZERO; i < IN_LEN; i++) {
    if (bits_left >= ALPH_SIZE) {
      ret[out_byte] |= (UNPACKED[i] << (bits_left - ALPH_SIZE));
      bits_left -= ALPH_SIZE;
    } else {
      ret[out_byte] |= (UNPACKED[i] >> (ALPH_SIZE - bits_left));
      bits_left = ALPH_SIZE - bits_left;
      out_byte++;
      ret[out_byte] |= (UNPACKED[i] << (BYTE_SIZE - bits_left));
      bits_left = BYTE_SIZE - bits_left;
    }
  }
  return ret;
}
```

I'm using Rcpp, which is an R interface for C++. `RawVector` is in fact `vector` of `char`'s.

This code works just perfectly - except it is too slow. I'm performing operations bit by bit while I could vectorize it somehow. And here is a question - is there any library or tool to do it? I'm not acknowledged with C++ tools.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @PaulEvans, sorry, I've rewritten code from Rcpp :/

Comment: This is tough the vectorize, lots of edge cases, if you can commit to a (few) particular ALPH_SIZE(s) it would be doable to vectorize each of them as a special case

Comment: On the other hand, if you have fast PEXT (so on Intel Haswell or newer, Ryzen implements it as well but inefficiently), that makes it easy

Comment: I would move out the main body in a separate function to let the compiler optimize it. My guess is that gcc (other?) does not cope well with a `Rcpp::RawVector` class

Comment: You could do this as a lookup table.  The 3 bits and 8 bits are relative prime, so you'd need a lookup table of size 6^8 = 1679616 for every set of 8 characters, returning 24 bits (3 bytes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to unroll your loop, so optimizer could make something useful out of it. It will also get rid of your `if`, which kills any chance for quick performance. Something like this:

```
int i = 0;
for(i = 0; i + 8 <= IN_LEN; i += 8) {
  ret[out_byte    ] = (UNPACKED[i]         ) | (UNPACKED[i + 1] << 3) | (UNPACKED[i + 2] << 6);
  ret[out_byte + 1] = (UNPACKED[i + 2] >> 2) | (UNPACKED[i + 3] << 1) | (UNPACKED[i + 4] << 4) | (UNPACKED[i + 5] << 7);
  ret[out_byte + 2] = (UNPACKED[i + 5] >> 1) | (UNPACKED[i + 6] << 2) | (UNPACKED[i + 7] << 5);
  out_byte += 3;
} 
for (; i < IN_LEN; i++) {
  if (bits_left >= ALPH_SIZE) {
    ret[out_byte] |= (UNPACKED[i] << (bits_left - ALPH_SIZE));
    bits_left -= ALPH_SIZE;
  } else {
    ret[out_byte] |= (UNPACKED[i] >> (ALPH_SIZE - bits_left));
    bits_left = ALPH_SIZE - bits_left;
    out_byte++;
    ret[out_byte] |= (UNPACKED[i] << (BYTE_SIZE - bits_left));
    bits_left = BYTE_SIZE - bits_left;
  }
}
```

This will allow optimizer to vectorize whole thing (assuming it's smart enough). With your current implementation i doubt any current compiler can find out, that your code loops after 3 written bytes and abuse it.

EDIT:
with sufficient constexpr / template magic you might be able to write some universal handler for body of the loop. Or just cover all small values (like write specialized template function for every bitcount from 1 to let's say 16). Packing values bitwise after 16 bits is overkill.

Answer (score 2):

> This code works just perfectly - except it is too slow.

Then you probably want to try out 4-bits/letter.  Trading space for time.  If 4-bits meets your compression needs (just 33.3% larger) then your code works on nibbles which will be much faster and simpler than tri-bits.

Comment: Well, you're right, but sometimes I also need to encode alphabets of e.g. 17 letters - then I need 5 bits. I'd like my code to be universal.

Comment: @DominikRafacz Then just use a standard compression library like [LZO](http://www.oberhumer.com/opensource/lzo/).

Comment: Is there really any need to reduce the size of your characters? If not, you can just use `std::string` which should be plenty optimized. Plus, your cpu can just work on your string bytewise instead of unpacking it, doing calculations and packing it again...

Comment: @DominikRafacz If saving size is really important, you could even pack 3 letters per byte (actually `n*log(256)/log(6)` letters inside `n` bytes). But whether that is the most efficient way, is questionable.

Comment: @jan.sende As I've mentioned, i'm doing the project in R and I need to keep data as R objects, so I cannot use std::string

Comment: @DominikRafacz You should be able to use `std::string` as long as you hide it from the interface...